# Help with file transfer from windows to ubuntu

Tags: windows, files, file-sharing

I have looked long and hard for this, but can't find exactly what I'm looking for. I want to edit videos on my Linux computer because of how much better the software is for editing. I record videos on my Windows computer which are mostly tutorial videos using an Elgato capture card these files are very big.

The question is: How can I set up a wireless file transfer from Windows to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Share the files from your windows computer by right clicking on the folder that contains them, and picking "Sharing". Give it some basic level of access.

1. Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd`, then click ok.
2. type `ipconfig` and get the IP address of your wireless adapter.
3. From your Ubuntu machine, open a new file window and click (from the menu bar) GO --> Enter Location
4. type `smb://[ip address here]`
5. If you're prompted for credentials, enter either your windows credentials or the ones you set up when you shared the folder.

Comment: thank you i didnt need it in that much of laymans terms but hey helpful to anyone else thanks for the reply

Comment: Did this help solve your issue?

Comment: nit fully because when i click the share it has an error sign trianglw with ! point in it that is by the create homegroup button or tab this is windows 7 by the way

Comment: Well - I'm no pro at troubleshooting Windows 7 sharing outside of a domain environment. I'd suggest following the instructions below to set up a share on your linux PC as an "inbound" sharing folder that you can access from Windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can also go the other way and set the share on our Linux machine, you can follow these instructions on how to do that.

[help.ubuntu.com - How to create a network share](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated%2C%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)

Procedures

All commands must be done as root (precede each command with 'sudo' or use 'sudo su').

Install Samba

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install samba
```

Set a password for your user in Samba

```
    sudo smbpasswd -a <user_name>
```

Note: Samba uses a separate set of passwords than the standard Linux system accounts (stored in /etc/samba/smbpasswd), so you'll need to create a Samba password for yourself. This tutorial implies that you will use your own user and it does not cover situations involving other users passwords, groups, etc...

Tip1: Use the password for your own user to facilitate.

Tip2: Remember that your user must have permission to write and edit the folder you want to share.
Eg.:
            sudo chown  /var/opt/blah/blahblah
            sudo chown : /var/opt/blah/blahblah

Tip3: If you're using another user than your own, it needs to exist in your system beforehand, you can create it without a shell access using the following command :
            sudo useradd USERNAME --shell /bin/false

You can also hide the user on the login screen by adjusting lightdm's configuration, in /etc/lightdm/users.conf add the newly created user to the line :
            hidden-users=

Create a directory to be shared

```
mkdir /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>
```

Make a safe backup copy of the original smb.conf file to your home folder, in case you make an error

```
sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf ~
```

Edit the file "/etc/samba/smb.conf"

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Once "smb.conf" has loaded, add this to the very end of the file:

```
    [<folder_name>]
    path = /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>
    valid users = <user_name>
    read only = no
```

Tip: There Should be in the spaces between the lines, and note que also there should be a single space both before and after each of the equal signs.

Restart the samba:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Once Samba has restarted, use this command to check your smb.conf for any syntax errors

```
testparm
```

To access your network share

```
      sudo apt-get install smbclient
```

## List all shares:

```
      smbclient -L //<HOST_IP_OR_NAME>/<folder_name> -U <user>
```

## connect:

```
      smbclient //<HOST_IP_OR_NAME>/<folder_name> -U <user>
```

To access your network share use your username () and password through the path "smb:////" (Linux users) or "\\\" (Windows users). Note that "" value is passed in "[]", in other words, the share name you entered in "/etc/samba/smb.conf".

Note: The default user group of samba is "WORKGROUP".

Source

```
http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_147/article_548-samba-quick-setup-on-ubuntu-1004.htm
```

Comment: Could you please be elaborate more here and link to the site only as source. This would vastly improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: @Videonauth, while I agree with you , I have seen the opposite asked as well, I looked at an answer earlier today that the person the answer in full detail, and someone told them to just link to the answer if it has been answered before.  So this seems to be a 50 50 as to who is watching and their opinions on answers.

Comment: When it is an answer on SE yes, i would have as well said o.k. rather flag it as duplicate instead of posting a link at all in an answer, but since you're linking to Ubuntu help site you can copy & paste some essential parts here and link to read further.

Comment: @Videonauth OK, cool, still learning the ground rules here, thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks for the reply although i think im gonna go the easier rout and do what the first answer instructs but thank you all

Comment: No problem, there are always 10 ways to answer a question.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a free file manager with GUI [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php). You can copy files in one click.

[image]
After creating connection you have one panel with your local computer and a panel with a remote computer.